# Why My torrent downloading hangs my computer?

Tags: windows-7, bittorrent, utorrent

I am downloading a game, it is almost 90% complete. Now, when I open my utorrent software, it hangs my computer. I am trying to copy-paste that game so that I can save that 90% file but its not successfully paste, its hang again. What is the reason behind this and what is the solution?

**Update**  now something new happen, "My computer" or any folder is not opening, when I open it, PC again hangs.

Comment: Your description is very vague. What *precisely* does "hangs my computer" mean? Does the display blank? Does the mouse pointer stop moving?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're running out of diskspace on your HDD from the info you provided.
If this is not the issue it could be trying to write to a corrupt segment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows 8/8.1 then forget µTorrent and instead switch to [qBittorrent](http://www.qbittorrent.org/) and in the advanced configuration options of that set the maximum outbound connections to 10 and you should still download full-speed without hanging or resource problems.

Source: happened to me.

Note: I hope that is a legal download you have going.

Comment: Darn, didn't see your Windows 7 tag, try qBittorrent anyway - it is a better program than µTorrent and it is also completely free: it doesn't shove advertisements in your face, it is open-source.

Comment: I am using Windows 7, the torrent seems fine. Now what should I do? I want to save that 90% file also.

Comment: I advise you to try qBittorrent and redownload.  Sorry, it is a waste of a download but µTorrent really isn't the best client out there.